# Logging into website that doesnt use a POST request - web-scraping with Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to log into the website(using requests get/post) https://www.robertparker.com/sign-in
neither chrome or mozilla can see these sessions.

Please point me in the right direction, There are no post requests for logging in, i believe they are using javascript, however i still cant see the server or any parametmers, only google analytics and facebook sessions.

```
<https://imgur.com/9MB92eX>
<https://imgur.com/xjamW7Q>
<https://imgur.com/14RyE7i>
<https://imgur.com/AsimSwR>
```

Comment: Can you login on the website without javascript enabled on your browser?

Comment: I'll answer my own question: NO, because the login is done via websckets (https://www.robertparker.com/sockjs/).

Answer (score 1):

`payload = {'at-field-username_and_email': 'your_nick', 'at-field-password': 'your_password'}`

This one not working?